# Python - read file - increment number - save file

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I hope you can help with something quite simple, but im clearly not having clarity working it out.

I have a bunch of images (image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg...you get the picture.)

I have a python script that I would like to read a file which contains the number of the image last sent, increment it by 1, and save the file with the new number, so the next time it runs, it would pick up and increment the next number. Image1 becomes Image 2 etc etc

Ive done some looking around and failing miserably and overcomplicating what I think is something quite simple.

Can someone save me from my torment??

Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Which of the three parts is giving you problems? What problems? Reading and writing files is part of pretty much any basic tutorial, so I'm having problems guessing what your actual question is.

Comment: I know...Ulrich...Im just having a blank moment and cant think straight on something simple. Thankfully people are helping my brain snap :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt','r+') as f:
    data = int(f.read())
    data += 1

    f.truncate(0) # Go to the beginning of the file, clearing the file
    f.write(str(data)) # write the data at the beginning of the file
```

Comment: This code will read an int from a file and increment it.

Comment: It will fail to write `myfile`...

Comment: Oops! Thanks for that catch. Updated it.

Comment: You can call `f.truncate(0)` immediately after the read and save yourself a call to `seek`. (You also need to convert `data` back to a `str`, or use something like `print(data, file=f)` to have the conversion done for you.)

Comment: you guys are awesome!!!!! Thanks @SimonWalker and mark-setchell and chepner
Superstars

Comment: Sorry again....do I need to set write permissions on the file....it doesnt seem to be updating?

Thanks guys!